# POSIX-compliant elevation detection

Tags: shell-script, shell, permissions, sudo, root

I'm writing a script that should be as POSIX compliant as possible, so I'm avoiding bashims. It requires elevated permissions (root) for some parts, and prompts the user if necessary - which requires *checking whether the current user is root*.

There are various approaches, e.g. checking `UID`, `EUID`, `id -u`, etc. These are covered in many questions related to the detection itself: [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15853/how-can-a-script-check-if-its-being-run-as-root), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215973/how-to-check-if-running-as-root-in-a-bash-script), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669950/difference-between-euid-and-uid), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455684/difference-between-real-user-id-effective-user-id-and-saved-user-id), [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362428/how-do-i-determine-if-a-shell-script-is-running-with-root-permissions), etc., but they are usually bash-related, and have posix-related warnings in comments as an afterthought.

I don't know which shells support which methods. Is there a single approach that is POSIX compliant and would work on most shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id -u` is [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html), so any POSIX-compliant environment should support

```
[ "$(id -u)" = 0 ]
```

as a test for effective root.

My tests on Busybox (with its `ash` and `id`) suggest that it supports the above, at least with the compilation options used for my Busybox. (I imagine it’s possible to build a Busybox which doesn’t meet the POSIX spec for these features, but then it would be out of scope for your question really.)